# Java surround a 2d array with default element

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to expand my current 2d array filled with elements, take for example String [n] [n] array.

Is there an easy way to solve this. A one liner or do I have to iterate through the new array. Because this gives me problems because the current array is filled with 0123456789 (chiffers) and stars* and points .

And the row 0, row max, column 0, column max have to be filled with the number 9 in the expanded 2d array

Comment: What is your preconditions and desired result? What do you mean by "surrounding"?

Comment: Surrounding: current array + row above and under + colom left and right.

Comment: First, there are no 2d arrays in Java. nor other multidimensional arrays. 2d array is just simulation: array of objects which are arrays of objects. Second, there are no built-in feature for your request in language or standard libraries, so you should implement it by your own using, yes, iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `java.util.Arrays` it has `Arrays.copyOf` where you can give the new dimension.. `Arrays.fill` where you can fill new values for specified range. Since you have a 2d Array you need at least 1 for loop...